# How can I show the remaining time for a caffeinate command?

Tags: macos, terminal, sleep-wake

After running caffeinate with a command such as `caffeinate -s -m -i -t 172800 &`, how can I show the remaining time with a subsequent command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pmset -g assertions` will show the `caffeinate`-generated assertion (among others) along with how many seconds remain:

```
   pid 23694(caffeinate): [0x0013076c0005a0ed] 00:37:55 PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep named: "caffeinate command-line tool" 
    Details: caffeinate asserting for 7200 secs
    Localized=THE CAFFEINATE TOOL IS PREVENTING SLEEP.
    Timeout will fire in 4924 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
```